# INSERT INTO Não envia os dados para a base de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","esferinf_fpessoa","*****","esferinf_factura");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql = ($con, "INSERT INTO Entregas (dia, cliente, toalhetes, higienico, bidons)
VALUES ('$dia, $cliente',$toalhetes, $higienico, $bidons)");
$result = mysqli_query($sql);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful".
if($result){
    header('Location: index.php');
}
else {
    echo "ERROR";
}
```

Contudo, os dados não são enviados para a BD.
Qual é o problema?

Answer (score 6):

Na sua string de consulta, remova a variavel `$con`, mudando

```
$sql = ($con, "INSERT INTO Entregas (dia, cliente, toalhetes, higienico, bidons)
VALUES ($dia, $cliente,$toalhetes, $higienico, $bidons)");
```

para

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Entregas (dia, cliente, toalhetes, higienico, bidons)
VALUES ($dia, $cliente,$toalhetes, $higienico, $bidons)";
```

O [mysqli_query()](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query) no modo procedural pede dois argumentos: a conexão, e a string de consulta. Seu código deve ficar assim:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

É recomendado que utilizar *prepared statements* para evitar sql injection. Utilizando isso, seu código deve ficar assim:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Entregas (dia, cliente, toalhetes, higienico, bidons)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssss", $dia, $cliente, $toalhetes, $higienico, $bidons);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

em `stmt_bind_param()` o `sssss` significa o tipo do argumento, ou seja cinco argumentos do tipo string.

```
s: para 'string'
i: para 'inteiro'
d: para 'double'
b: para 'blob'
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize **aspas** nas variáveis de inserção:

```
$sql = ($con, "INSERT INTO Entregas (dia, cliente, toalhetes, higienico, bidons)
VALUES ('$dia', '$cliente','$toalhetes', '$higienico', '$bidons')");
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
```